# Building and running C++ console application with standard 'main' entry in VS (2010)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and started console application project.

VS generates the entry point as `_tmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])`. Instead, I need the entry point `main(int argc, char *argv[])` - just a standard console application.

What are the settings that I need to change from defaults and how does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create an empty console project (there's a setting when you pick the project type), then add a "main.cpp" file and add the standard `main` function. Works every time for me. Actually, I never use the premade/generated C++ projects due to overhead, precompiled headers, etc.

Comment: Thank you! Probably it will be a good starting point in seeing the differences of the settings in those projects.

Comment: No, sure, they can be good, if they're worth the added complexity. A small 2 or 3 files program won't need them.

Comment: "Start over" isn't a real strong answer... I want to *fix an existing project*.

Comment: @Cuadue Then you should probably create a new question with details for your specific case. The user in this case had issues starting from scratch, so I'd consider this a perfectly valid answer (for his case).

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new project, mark the "empty project" box.
Then you can write any main you want.